# Failed to make a directory using Chilkat lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ftp, chilkat

I am using the Chilkat gem version 9.5.0.65. and When I try to create a folder using sftp credentials it return false, while when I use Net::SFTP it creates the folder.

As the chilkat library is compiled so I am unable to debug the issue. Can anyone suggest me what can be the issue.

I have tried with other library with which  I am able to do. But I want to use chilkat

```
ftp = Chilkat::CkSFtp.new()
make ftp connection
ftp.CreateDir("/a/b")
#this is returing false
```

I want to know the reason behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "a/b" instead of "/a/b".   When you say "/a/b" you're passing an absolute path, and therefore trying to create directory "a" in the root of the hard drive.  You want to create a directory relative to the HOME directory of your SSH account.